# Catch only character encoding issues in XmlException

Tags: c#, xml, string, character-encoding, xmlexception

I'm using System.Xml to parse xml documents. Sometimes the xml documents contain unencodable characters and then an `XmlException` gets thrown. In those cases, I want to retry parsing the document with a forced encoding, like this:

```
try {
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load()
} catch (XmlException xe) {
    // Retry here with another encoding..
}
```

This works fairly well except that XmlException gets thrown for all types of xml problems even those not caused by character encoding issues. In those cases I do not want to retry parsing. So is there a way to figure out whether the XmlException was caused by character encoding problems or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is no, there is no way to robustly find out what caused the XmlException.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the exception looks like, but surely by checking the contents of `xe.Message` or `xe.InnerException` you would be able to determine the type of exception?

Comment: No, neither alternative has that info.